# His accomplishments could rest comfortably on an eyelash

Tags: sentence-meaning

There is an 2011 American comedy movie named "Change-Up" produced and directed by David Dobkin starring Ryan Reynolds and Jason Bateman. The following sentence is taken from this film when Ryan Reynolds's father is talking to Jason Bateman and Reynolds's closest friend to talk to him into changing is life while Reynolds is acting up and doesn't tend to take any step forward in his life.

> - His accomplishments could rest comfortably on an eyelash.

What does it mean? Is it a proverb?

Comment: It's not a stock phrase, but think about: what kind of thing could rest comfortably on an eyelash?

Comment: For not googling the phrase to begin with, which would have immediately told you if it was a proverb or not, I am casting my vote to close.

Comment: The meaning is absolutely clear, look up the words "accomplishments", "rest", "comfortably" and "eyelash". It's a joke, it's sarcasm, it has lilttle to do with language, I could say exactly the same thing in Italian.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. Good question. I just turned on subtitle to find out the meaning. The translation was something too similar to a proverb in our language. I guessed there should be something wrong with the translation. I brought it up here to make sure about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a stock phrase.  It's more of a picturesque joke / criticism of the *character* of Reynolds' character in the movie.

You have to imagine what could "rest comfortably" without disturbing even something as small and light as an eyelash (see below for the answer, if you can't figure it out).

This sort of "backwards" imagery is not uncommon, I think, in many languages.  Consider this similar example:

> His dancing was as light and graceful as a herd of elephants.

Obviously, elephants are neither *light* nor *graceful*, so the implication is that his dancing is *loud* and *clumsy*.

Answer (mouse-over to see spoiler)

> In the same way "rest comfortably on an eyelash" means, more or less, something that is *insubstantial* or even *nonexistent*.  It means Reynolds' character has had *no* significant accomplishments in his life.

This kind of expression is usually *sarcastic*, but it can be humorous or mean-spirited, depending on the context.